# /crtend.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a C++ code using a cross-compiler built using crosstool-ng. It is throwing the following error:

```
:~/Desktop$ alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ -static new1.cpp -o hello  
/home/iiitd/local/x-tools/alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: error in /home/iiitd/local/x-tools/alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/6.3.1/crtend.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.

crosstool-NG version: crosstool-ng-1.23.0.rc2
Binutils Version: 2.28
glibc version 2.25
gcc linaro 6.3-2017.02
Host OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have to specify a sysroot using the `--sysroot=<path>`?

Comment: @nucleon I have specified the PATH as :  $ export PATH=$PATH:/home/iiitd/local/x-tools/alphaev4-unknown-linux-gnu/bin . I am not aware if I have to specify any sysroot path.